# Fading in/out scroller animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a slider that slides from right to left as the user scrolls down the page.

I want the slider to fade out when the last slide is out of view when the user scrolls down, and I want the slider to fade in when the last slide is in view when the user scrolls up.

An example of what I want can be seen [here](https://career.myrealtrip.com/)

I have the slider working fine but am having trouble with the fade out/fade in animation.

[image]

My idea was to first store an `opacity` value of `1` in a `useRef`

```
const countRefOpacity = useRef(1);
```

And add a `wheel` event to my window

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
    };
  }, []);
```

My handleWheel function decreases my slider `opacity` when the user scrolls down a certain point and increases the `opacity` when the user scrolls up a certain point

```
  const handleWheel = (e) => {
    if (window.scrollY >= pan.current?.offsetTop * 2 && e.deltaY > 0) {
      countRefOpacity.current = countRefOpacity.current - 0.007;
      slider.current.style.opacity = countRefOpacity.current;
    } else if (window.scrollY < pan.current?.offsetTop * 2 && e.deltaY < 0) {
      countRefOpacity.current = countRefOpacity.current + 0.007;
      slider.current.style.opacity = countRefOpacity.current;
    }
  };
```

I can see the fade out animation working when the user scrolls down, but the fade in animation is pretty slow when the user scrolls up.

How can I revise my code so I can make the fade in/fade out animation smooth and natural?

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-cards-4-xqw4l?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a CSS property to change smoothly, you can use the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property, e.g. in your case

```css
transition: opacity .5s;
```

So, assuming I understood your question correctly, I would probably use the `transition` property as well as add an event listener to the window's [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event) event that checks whether the user has scrolled past a certain point and updates the opacity accordingly, i.e. sets it to `1` if it's before that point and to `0` otherwise. There's no need for you to calculate a delta since the `transition` property will handle the fade-in/fade-out for you.

Also, I believe you probably want to use `scroll` instead of `wheel`, since I think `wheel` only fires when you use a mouse wheel and doesn't apply to other types of scrolling.